# SQL:Updating a value (coming from destination table) in the source table after copying the data from source to destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The tables I have are;

```
TableA {TableA_OID, TableB_OID, SomeFields} //Source Table

TableB{TableB_OID, SomeFields} //Destination Table
```

I have to copy some data from source table to destination table, and on success i want to take the primary key identity field(`TableB_OID`) of destination table back to update (`TableB_OID`) field in the source table.

Comment: Unless you have a TableA_OID in TableB, you will need some form of business key to match on in order to be able to perform the update e.g. name and address providing a unique combination of values that will allow you update one table based on the other.

Comment: I tried the OUTPUT INSERTED.MyPrimaryKey into #tempTable, and now I have 2 temp tables, one with Source Primary Keys, In Order, and the other one having Destination Primary Keys, also In Order. How do I merge them? And is it guaranteed that the data is inserted in the same order the select query gets the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work, but I'd play with it with some reasonable size data sets first, to be sure:

```
DECLARE @TA TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), AID INT)
INSERT @TA(AID) SELECT TableA_OID FROM TABLEA  -- ORDER BY data desc 
DECLARE @TB TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), BID INT)

INSERT TableB( data )
OUTPUT Inserted.TableB_OID INTO @TB(BID)
SELECT data 
FROM @TA TA JOIN TableA ON TA.AID=TableA.TableA_OID ORDER BY TA.ID

SELECT * FROM @TA
SELECT * FROM @TB

UPDATE TableA 
SET TableB_OID=TB.BID
FROM @TB TB 
    JOIN @TA TA ON TB.ID=TA.ID
    JOIN TableA ON TA.AID=TableA.TableA_OID

SELECT * FROM TableA
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

First of all we're going to impose an order on the data we pull from table A, and use an identity column in a temporary table to record that order, linked to the original table A records. We'll then insert data into table B using that order, and record the resulting output into another temporary table. Again, we'll use an identity to record the sequence. We'll then use the identity values from the two temporary tables to link the tableA and tableB rows

Comment: You inserted data in to TA in descending order, but in TB it is in ascending order, is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM, YOU ROCK! (just one change, please remove the desc in order by in the second line)

Comment: Sorry, yes, the descending was just to change the order of my test data a bit so I could check it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select the `scope_identity()`?

This will do a single row:

```
    INSERT INTO TableB (
        something
    )
    VALUES (
        'Some Value'
    )

    DECLARE @Id int
    SET @Id = scope_identity()

    UPDATE TableA SET tableB_OID = @Id WHERE TableA_OID = TableAId
```

Comment: this will do for one, I have to do this in a stored procedure for bulk data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy more than one row at once, something like the following will work:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(ID int, data varchar(50))

INSERT TableB( data )
OUTPUT Inserted.TableB_OID, INSERTed.data INTO @data
SELECT data FROM TableA 


UPDATE TableA 
SET TableB_OID=D.ID
FROM @data D JOIN TableA ON D.DATA=TableA.data
```

It does make an assumption though, that there is a unique key in your "SomeField" (column "data") in my example, otherwise you can't relate the identity data back into tableA. If there is, then fine, otherwise, as Steph said, you'll need to add a TableA_OID field into TableB to be able to do the join to write back the data

Comment: Of course, if you have a key you can match on, then all of this is overkill as you could simply join the tables directly anyway, without the need for the OUTPUT clause (ie, just join to TableB directly, instead of @data)

Comment: that is the problem, i did the exactly same thing creating a tempTable and copying all inserted primary keys in to that, but in OUTPUT INSERTED part, can i select something from TableA.AnyField?

Comment: so now, I have two temp tables, one have TableA_OID and the other one has TABLEB_OID which are just inserted. Now, the data in both are ordered and just merging the two tables would do my task, but how do I do that?

Comment: Okay, I'll post an alternative